# Simple how to make a application directory path

Tags: c#, directory

Ok I know it is simple but I have forgotten how to do it. I want to create a folder in a directory but if I do `"C:\Users\George\AppData\Roaming\myprogram"` this only woks for me it will not work with everybody that I send it to

I tried `"C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Myprogram"` but it says access denied so what can I use to make this work for everyone?

Here is the segment of code I am using to do this if it helps :

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\SkypeAdmin");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\SkypeAdmin\mem");
}
```

and I tried :

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\SkypeAdmin");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\SkypeAdmin\mem");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach predefines a path for the folder so the location would only be valid for you and anyone else who has the specified loacation.

You can try this instead:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DirectoryInfo di  =  Directory.CreateDirectory(skypeAdminPath);
    DirectoryInfo di2  =  Directory.CreateDirectory(skypeMemPath);
}

string skypeAdminPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "SkypeAdmin\\";

string skypeMemPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "SkypeAdmin\\mem\\";
```

Using `Path.Combine`:

```
string skypeAdminPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SkypeAdmin\\");
string skypeMemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SkypeAdmin\\mem\\");
```

Comment: Directory.CreateDirectory has handling for that, unlike Path.Combine.

Comment: @pcnThird above code wont work `string skypeMemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "\\SkypeAdmin\\mem\\");` instead required code is `string skypeMemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "SkypeAdmin\\mem\\");` please do note `\\` removed

Comment: Are you getting any errors or exceptions? It worked just fine; the extra '\\' is redundant, though. It's editing time... once again. Thanks.

Comment: No that will return invalid string. try it out

Comment: @pcnThird Me too, i faced it in older versions of .net too. doesn't look strange for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CommonAppDataPath

```
string path = Application.CommonAppDataPath;//for folder with version
```

this may change every version of your application, if you dont want this behavior and you want `Same Directory` for all the version of your App you can use this

```
string path = Directory.GetParent(Application.CommonAppDataPath);
```

the directory will be readily available when your code executes above line, this is created on demand.

**Note:**
I assume that you want to create some directory for all users and use it. instead of doing so you can used shared Directory and access it from any user.

This is how a sample `CommonAppData` path look like
`C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\WindowsFormsApplicationTest\1.0.0.0`

Typically `CommonAppDataBase\CompanyName\ProductName\Version`

Comment: ok how would this need to look for  me to make my folder for my  application and sub folders and i need to create files there a lot and read the files so how can i fix the generic directory

Comment: You don't need to create a folder for your application. when above code is executed it will be readily availabe. if at all you want to differentiate folders for each user you can create subfolder in above directory with sub folder name as `UserName`. You get  `Delete, Read, Write` to any file inside this folder without any restriction.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstar no i want to make a folder it needs to store permanent files that are created its just to i can sore all the files that my app makes it

Comment: no i want to make a folder it needs to store permanent files that are created its just to i can sore all the files that my app makes it

Comment: Yes you can do it by above mentioned way, what is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: ok thank you it works but it needs to be run as admin so i will just force it to run as admin that's why i wanted to do it to appdata

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Enviroment.GetFolderPath` for that:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
        Enviroment.GetFolderPath(Enviroment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        @"\SkypeAdmin\"));
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(
        Enviroment.GetFolderPath(Enviroment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
        @"\SkypeAdmin\mem\"));
```

That does exactly what (I think) you mean to do. Your solution doesn't work because there is no folder called `[User]` or `User` in the system, so you can't create a folder in there, and `Directory.CreateDirectory` doesn't replace that for the user path for you.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstar yes i do i just needed to know what i have to replace with user or [user] to make it work because i have to save text files and lots of outer stuff there all the time with the application

Comment: @Gerard2202 You can't make it work like that, you need to use this.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstar ok thankyou for your help it dose not work for some reason but thanks

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstar it just dose not make the folder i have put it in the form 1 class so it should auto load but nothing happens

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstar yes the rest of my code runs fine and i have put it in the public for so it should load